# WIFI keep asking password

Tags: wireless

This question has been asked in various threads and I tried all options, but I am still getting the problem: wifi network is keep asking the password. How can I resolve it ? Thanks

Comment: Go to network icon, select Edit connections, delete the settings for your wifi network. Then try to reconnect to create new settings. Or do `sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/accesspointname` and reconnect . Same thing

Comment: @Serg, I tried this option, but its giving the same problem again

Comment: OK. Well, I guess we can go a bit further with this - run the [diagnostic script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/295286), link the results here, and we will see.

Comment: Hi, I ran it, it just shows ########## wireless info START ##########, nothing else

Comment: This is not right. Run it again. Follow the instructions. You should have info about your wireless card, drivers, and connections listed bellow that line

Comment: Hi, Yes, I was doing it wrong, the output is in the link provided. I cannot post it here as it exceeds the character limits. http://1drv.ms/1KWrPjF

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Although this is an old post/comment. I tried your suggestion, but it showed `cannot remove ... : No such file or directory.` Could you help with this?

Comment: @user55777 More recent versions of Ubuntu use netplan instead of network-manager, so it is quite possible for the file or the directory not to exist. Perhaps a new question on the site , with your Ubuntu version and the steps you've tried, could attract those who know about more this issue in context of your OS release and specific issue, and they just might share more light on what's happening.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy oh... yes, I am using ubuntu 18.04 and actually post a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263315/dual-system-win10-can-connect-to-wireless-but-ubuntu-18-04-cannot-and-keep-aski) yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the incorrect driver is installed. With a temporary working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot and let us know if the performance has improved.

Exra credit, by the way, for posting the wireless script on Microsoft Drive!

Comment: Oh, the irony... **;-)**

Comment: @chili555 I tried your answer, but it still keeps asking the password. I am using ubuntu18.04 and also post a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263315/dual-system-win10-can-connect-to-wireless-but-ubuntu-18-04-cannot-and-keep-aski) yesterday.

Comment: @user55777 A fix for a Broadcom wireless device will never help your Intel device. I am answering your question in a few minutes.