# Dual system: win10 can connect to wireless but ubuntu 18.04 cannot and keep asking password

Tags: networking, password, iwlwifi

I have a Lenovo laptop, on which I installed win10 and ubuntu 18.04. Recently, with Ubuntu system I cannot connect to the wireless network of my home, however, with win10 it can connect. With Ubuntu, it is able to detect the wifi, while after entering the password, it cannot connect successfully and consistently pop up the window requiring to key in the password.

I am not very familiar with debugging problems on Ubuntu and not sure if this problem is related to the dual system regime. I have already read some related post here but those answers or comments fail to resolve my issue. With the command:`lspci -knn |grep Net -A3`

I got

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:1130]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

This picture shows the panel of the router.

[image]
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I own and use successfully two Intel wireless devices. I have honed a few techniques in several years and thousands of forum posts.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it may slightly affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Comment: would you mind explaining more details. 1. How to check the settings of the router. How to change to WPA2-AES mode? 2. By checking `sudo iw reg get`, I saw `country 00: DFS-UNSET` preceding lots of texts... 3. "substitute your country code", replace which word in `sudo iw reg set IS` by my country code?

Comment: In the example I gave, if you look at the list of country codes on the Wikipedia link, the code for Iceland is IS. If your country is, for example Germany, then the Wikipedia page says your code is DE so you'd substitute DE for IS in my example. If you are in Australia, then AU and so forth.

Comment: You change the encryption method, channel, etc. in the administration pages of the router. Here is an example: http://sonic.net/support/ss/linksys/setup/basic-setup.gif