# How do I troubleshoot an intermittent wifi connection, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wireless

Today my wifi on an Ubuntu 20.04 desktop became very unstable and mostly not usable. What can I do to troubleshoot this problem?

### Problem

My wireless connection is unstable.

Connecting to the wifi network initially seems OK: I have internet access, but it is slow in a web browser. Then within a few seconds I have no network access. It comes back sometimes for a few seconds, then disappears again.

Network manager seems to think it is connected to the internet most of the time; the little network manager desktop applet thingy in the top panel mostly looks connected with very strong signal strength, but will on occasion show a question mark. But I clearly don't have stable internet access. Pings of google.com are slow or show lots of packet loss.

On the desktop wired ethernet works just fine, and no other machines on the wifi network have trouble. The Ubuntu 20.04 machine had no trouble with wifi until today. There have been no hardware or physical changes to my network or machines.

### Wireless info

To gather information, I used the script provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/861372), which produced this [wireless-info.txt](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/g74y9CQkBF/). To do this, I booted the machine, successfully connected to wired ethernet and downloaded the script. Then I connected to wifi and disconnected the wired connection. The internet trouble quickly started. Then I ran the script.

### Things I have tried that didn't seem to help

- Changed wifi.powersave in default-wifi-powersave-on.conf from 3 to 2, suggested [here](https://default-wifi-powersave-on.conf).
- Changed REGDOMAIN in /etc/default/crda to US, suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1263553/861372)
- Changed IPv4 DNS from Automatic to 8.8.8.8

Comment: Two SSIDs with the same name and roaming. Please consider my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453583/intel-ax201-wifi-adapter-disconnecting-frequently/1453593#1453593